# Failed to load viewstate composite control

Tags: c#, .net, viewstate, composite-controls

I have a composite control that contains a different set of child controls based on the value of one of it's properties at runtime.
Whenever there is a postback, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.
```

I have been googling this issue and changing the order of my child controls instantiation repeatedly without success.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?  The controls within the composite control function correctly by themselves without error.

Here is the composite control:

```
    [Serializable]
public enum AddEditType
{
    SelectList,
    SelectSingleItem,
    SelectSingleItemWithForm,
    Form
}
[Themeable(true)]
[Serializable]
public class AddEdit<TBO, TCriteria> : CompositeControl
    where TBO : Bll.BOBase
    where TCriteria : Bll.BaseCriteria
{
    #region Constructor
    public AddEdit(ObjectType myObjectType, AddEditType myType, EquatableList<TBO> myDataList, EditPageViewType myViewType)
    {
        this.ObjectType = myObjectType;
        this.Type = myType;
        this.myViewType = myViewType;
        cachedOriginalList = myDataList.Clone();
        cachedCurrentList = myDataList.Clone();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Fields
    private EditPageViewType myViewType = EditPageViewType.Read;
    private EquatableList<TBO> cachedOriginalList
    {
        get
        {
            // Get reference to cache
            ICacheManager cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
            // Look for cached data.
            string cacheKey = GenerateCacheKey("cachedOriginalList");
            EquatableList<TBO> myList = (EquatableList<TBO>)cache.GetData(cacheKey);
            return myList;
        }
        set
        {
            // Get reference to cache
            ICacheManager cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
            // Store the value in the cache.
            string cacheKey = GenerateCacheKey("cachedOriginalList");
            cache.Add(cacheKey, value);
        }
    }
    private EquatableList<TBO> cachedCurrentList
    {
        get
        {
            // Get reference to cache
            ICacheManager cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
            // Look for cached data.
            string cacheKey = GenerateCacheKey("cachedCurrentList");
            EquatableList<TBO> myList = (EquatableList<TBO>)cache.GetData(cacheKey);
            return myList;
        }
        set
        {
            // Get reference to cache
            ICacheManager cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
            // Store the value in the cache.
            string cacheKey = GenerateCacheKey("cachedCurrentList");
            cache.Add(cacheKey, value);
        }
    }
    private Label myTitle;
    private UpdatePanel myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel;
    private ButtonPanel myButtonPanel;
    private MyCompanygridview myCurrentEntriesGridView;
    private Panel myEditEntriesPanel;
    private HiddenField myModalPopupTargetControl;
    private ModalPopupExtender myEditEntriesPopup;
    private UpdatePanel myEditEntriesUpdatePanel;
    private Label myEditTitle;
    private Panel myEditContentPanel;
    private SearchGrid<TCriteria> mySearchGrid;
    private Button myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton;
    private Button myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton;
    private TCriteria mySearchCriteria;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of display that should be shown in the Add/Edit Control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of display that should be shown in the Add/Edit Control.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("AddEdit"),
    Description("Gets or sets the type of display that should be shown in the Add/Edit Control."),
    DefaultValue(null)]
    public AddEditType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return (AddEditType)ViewState["AddEditType"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["AddEditType"] = value;
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of items that should be shown in the Add/Edit Control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of items that should be shown in the Add/Edit Control.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("AddEdit"),
    Description("Gets or sets the type of items that should be shown in the Add/Edit Control."),
    DefaultValue(null)]
    public ObjectType ObjectType
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObjectType)ViewState["ObjectType"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ObjectType"] = value;
        }

    }
    public EquatableList<TBO> DataList
    {
        get
        {
            return cachedCurrentList;
        }
        set
        {
            cachedCurrentList = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the search criteria.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The search criteria.</value>
    public TCriteria SearchCriteria
    {
        get
        {
            return mySearchCriteria;
        }
        set
        {
            mySearchCriteria = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Overridden Methods
    protected override void RecreateChildcotrols()
    {
        EnsureChildcontrols();
    }
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();

        ButtonPanelType myButtonPanelType = ButtonPanelType.SelectList;
        string myEditEntriesTitle = "Select " + Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), this.ObjectType) + ":";
        switch (Type)
        {
            case AddEditType.Form:
                myButtonPanelType = ButtonPanelType.SelectList;
                myEditEntriesTitle = "Edit " + Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), this.ObjectType) + ":";
                break;
            case AddEditType.SelectList:
                myButtonPanelType = ButtonPanelType.SelectList;
                myEditEntriesTitle = "Select " + Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), this.ObjectType) + ":";
                mySearchGrid = new SearchGrid<TCriteria>(this.ObjectType);
                break;
            case AddEditType.SelectSingleItem:
                myButtonPanelType = ButtonPanelType.SelectSingleItem;
                myEditEntriesTitle = "Select " + Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), this.ObjectType) + ":";
                mySearchGrid = new SearchGrid<TCriteria>(this.ObjectType);
                break;
            case AddEditType.SelectSingleItemWithForm:
                myButtonPanelType = ButtonPanelType.SelectSingleItem;
                myEditEntriesTitle = "Select/Edit " + Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), this.ObjectType) + ":";
                mySearchGrid = new SearchGrid<TCriteria>(this.ObjectType);
                break;
        }


        AddEditParser parser = AddEditParserFactory.GetParser(this.ObjectType);

        // Define the Title Label
        myTitle = new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(myTitle);
        myTitle.ID = "lblTitle";
        myTitle.Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), this.ObjectType) + ":";

        // Define the Current Entries Update Panel
        myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        this.Controls.Add(myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel);
        myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.ID = "updpnlCurrentEntries";
        myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;


        // Define the Button Panel
        myButtonPanel = new ButtonPanel(myButtonPanelType, myViewType);
        myButtonPanel.AddButtonClick += new EventHandler(myButtonPanel_AddButtonClick);
        myButtonPanel.ResetButtonClick += new EventHandler(myButtonPanel_ResetButtonClick);
        myButtonPanel.RemoveSelectedButtonClick += new EventHandler(myButtonPanel_RemoveSelectedButtonClick);
        myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(myButtonPanel);            

        // Define the Current Entries MyCompanygridView using parser
        // and add it to the content template of the updatepanel.
        myCurrentEntriesGridView = new MyCompanygridview();
        parser.CreateGridViewColumns(ref myCurrentEntriesGridView);
        myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(myCurrentEntriesGridView);
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.ID = "gvCurrentEntries";
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.DataSource = cachedCurrentList;
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.AllowSorting = true;
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.Width = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit("100%");
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.AllowPaging = true;
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.EnableCustomPager = true;
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.SelectionType = MyCompanygridviewSelectionType.Multiple;



        // Define the Edit Entries Panel
        myEditEntriesPanel = new Panel();
        this.Controls.Add(myEditEntriesPanel);
        myEditEntriesPanel.ID = "pnlEditEntries";
        myEditEntriesPanel.CssClass = "modalWindow";


        // Define the HiddenField used as the TargetControlID 
        // for the ModalPopupExtender, and add it to the panel.
        myModalPopupTargetControl = new HiddenField();
        myEditEntriesPanel.Controls.Add(myModalPopupTargetControl);
        myModalPopupTargetControl.ID = "hfModalPopupTargetControl";


        // Define the ModalPopupExtender and add it to the panel.
        myEditEntriesPopup = new ModalPopupExtender();
        myEditEntriesPanel.Controls.Add(myEditEntriesPopup);
        myEditEntriesPopup.ID = "mpeEditEntries";
        myEditEntriesPopup.BackgroundCssClass = "modalBackground";
        myEditEntriesPopup.PopupControlID = "pnlEditEntries";
        myEditEntriesPopup.TargetControlID = "hfModalPopupTargetControl";



        // Define the Edit Entries Update Panel
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        myEditEntriesPanel.Controls.Add(myEditEntriesUpdatePanel);
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel.ID = "updpnlEditEntries";
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;


        // Define the Edit Entries Title
        myEditTitle = new Label();
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(myEditTitle);
        myEditTitle.ID = "lblEditTitle";
        myEditTitle.Text = myEditEntriesTitle;


        // Define the Edit Entries Content
        myEditContentPanel = new Panel();
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(myEditContentPanel);
        myEditContentPanel.ID = "pnlEditContent";
        switch (Type)
        {
            case AddEditType.Form:
                parser.CreateFormControls(ref myEditContentPanel, new Dictionary<SearchPanelControlType, string>());
                break;
            case AddEditType.SelectList:
                mySearchGrid = new SearchGrid<TCriteria>(this.ObjectType);
                mySearchGrid.GridView.SelectionType = MyCompanygridviewSelectionType.Multiple;
                mySearchGrid.SearchCriteria = this.mySearchCriteria;
                myEditContentPanel.Controls.Add(mySearchGrid);
                break;
            case AddEditType.SelectSingleItem:
                mySearchGrid = new SearchGrid<TCriteria>(this.ObjectType);
                mySearchGrid.GridView.SelectionType = MyCompanygridviewSelectionType.Single;
                mySearchGrid.SearchCriteria = this.mySearchCriteria;
                myEditContentPanel.Controls.Add(mySearchGrid);
                break;
            case AddEditType.SelectSingleItemWithForm:
                mySearchGrid = new SearchGrid<TCriteria>(this.ObjectType);
                mySearchGrid.GridView.SelectionType = MyCompanygridviewSelectionType.Single;
                mySearchGrid.SearchCriteria = this.mySearchCriteria;
                myEditContentPanel.Controls.Add(mySearchGrid);
                parser.CreateFormControls(ref myEditContentPanel, new Dictionary<SearchPanelControlType, string>());
                break;
        }

        // Define the Confirm/Cancel buttons
        myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton = new Button();
        myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton.Click += new EventHandler(myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton_Click);
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton);
        myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton.ID = "btnConfirmEditEntriesChanges";
        myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton.Text = "Save";
        myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton.CausesValidation = true;


        myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton = new Button();
        myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton.Click += new EventHandler(myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton_Click);
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton);
        myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton.ID = "btnCancelEditEntriesChanges";
        myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton.Text = "Cancel";
        myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton.CausesValidation = true;




        ConfigureDisplay();
    }


    //protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    //{
    //    AddAttributesToRender(writer);

    //    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);

    //    myTitle.RenderControl(writer);
    //    myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.RenderControl(writer);
    //    myEditEntriesPanel.RenderControl(writer);

    //    writer.RenderEndTag();
    //}
    #endregion

    #region Public Event Handlers
    #region Make the OnCancel event of the AddEdit control visible
    private static readonly object EventCancelEditKey = new object();
    public event EventHandler CancelEdit
    {
        add
        {
            Events.AddHandler(EventCancelEditKey, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            Events.RemoveHandler(EventCancelEditKey, value);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnCancelEdit(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler CancelEditHandler = (EventHandler)Events[EventCancelEditKey];
        if (CancelEditHandler != null)
        {
            CancelEditHandler(this, e);
        }
    }
    private void myCancelEditEntriesChangesButton_Click(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        myEditEntriesPopup.Hide();
        ResetEditEntriesControls();
        OnCancelEdit(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Make the OnConfirmEdit event of the AddEdit control visible
    private static readonly object EventConfirmEditKey = new object();
    public event EventHandler ConfirmEdit
    {
        add
        {
            Events.AddHandler(EventConfirmEditKey, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            Events.RemoveHandler(EventConfirmEditKey, value);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnConfirmEdit(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler ConfirmEditHandler = (EventHandler)Events[EventConfirmEditKey];
        if (ConfirmEditHandler != null)
        {
            ConfirmEditHandler(this, e);
        }
    }
    private void myConfirmEditEntriesChangesButton_Click(object source, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Type != AddEditType.Form)
        {
            EquatableList<TBO> myOldList = cachedCurrentList.Clone();

            try
            {
                List<Guid> mySelectedValues = mySearchGrid.GridView.SelectedValues;

                // Add each item in the SelectedValues list
                // to the cachedCurrentList
                foreach (Guid currentGUID in mySelectedValues)
                {
                    ObjectMetaDataDictionary myOMD = ObjectMetaDataDictionary.Instance;
                    Type _objectType = myOMD[this.ObjectType].BOClass;

                    TBO myObject = (TBO)Activator.CreateInstance(_objectType);

                    // Check to see if it already exists in the 
                    // cachedCurrentList. If it doesn't, add it.
                    if (!cachedCurrentList.ExistByID<TBO>(currentGUID))
                    {
                        Type _managerType = myOMD[this.ObjectType].ManagerClass;
                        Object[] myStaticMethodArguments = new Object[1];
                        myStaticMethodArguments.SetValue(currentGUID, 0);
                        MethodInfo myStaticMethodInfo = _managerType.GetMethod("GetItem");
                        myObject = (TBO)myStaticMethodInfo.Invoke(null, myStaticMethodArguments);


                        // If the Object is not null add it to the cachedCurrentList.
                        if (myObject != null)
                        {
                            cachedCurrentList.Add(myObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cachedCurrentList = myOldList.Clone();
                bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Base Policy");
                if (rethrow)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendFormat("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }



        myEditEntriesPopup.Hide();
        BindCurrentGrid();
        myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.Update();
        ResetEditEntriesControls();
        OnConfirmEdit(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion

    #region Private Event Handlers

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a string used to identify this control in the cache.
    /// </summary>
    private string GenerateCacheKey(string key)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", "AddEditControl", Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), this.Type), this.Context.Session.SessionID, key);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private void BindCurrentGrid()
    {
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.DataSource = cachedCurrentList;
        myCurrentEntriesGridView.DataBind();

    }
    protected void myButtonPanel_AddButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myEditEntriesPopup.Show();
    }
    protected void myButtonPanel_ResetButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cachedCurrentList = cachedOriginalList.Clone();
        BindCurrentGrid();
        myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.Update();
        ResetEditEntriesControls();
        myEditEntriesUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
    protected void myButtonPanel_RemoveSelectedButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EquatableList<TBO> myOldList = cachedCurrentList.Clone();

        try
        {
            List<Guid> mySelectedValues = mySearchGrid.GridView.SelectedValues;
            // Remove each item in the SelectedValues list from the cachedCurrentList
            foreach (Guid currentGUID in mySelectedValues)
            {
                cachedCurrentList.RemoveAll(delegate(TBO x) { return x.Id == currentGUID; });
            }
            BindCurrentGrid();
            myCurrentEntriesUpdatePanel.Update();
            ResetEditEntriesControls();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cachedCurrentList = myOldList.Clone();
            bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Base Policy");
            if (rethrow)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendFormat("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    private void ResetEditEntriesControls()
    {
        if (Type != AddEditType.Form)
        {
            // RESET SEARCH GRID
            mySearchGrid.GridView.SelectedValues = cachedOriginalList.ToListOfIDs();
            if (typeof(IDisabledFlg).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TBO)))
            {
                foreach (TBO item in cachedOriginalList)
                {
                    IDisabledFlg castedItem = (IDisabledFlg)item;
                    if (castedItem.DisabledFlg)
                    {
                        mySearchGrid.GridView.DisabledValues.Add(castedItem.Id);
                    }
                }
            }
            mySearchGrid.GridView.DataBind();
            mySearchGrid.SearchCriteria = this.mySearchCriteria;
        }
        if (Type == AddEditType.Form || Type == AddEditType.SelectSingleItemWithForm)
        {
            // Call parser to reset any other controls
            AddEditParser parser = AddEditParserFactory.GetParser(this.ObjectType);
            parser.SetFormControls<TBO>(null, ref myEditEntriesPanel);
        }
    }
    private void ConfigureDisplay()
    {
        myButtonPanel.ViewType = this.myViewType;
        switch (myViewType)
        {
            case EditPageViewType.Update:
                myCurrentEntriesGridView.Enabled = true;
                break;
            case EditPageViewType.Create:
                myCurrentEntriesGridView.Enabled = true;
                break;
            case EditPageViewType.Read:
                myCurrentEntriesGridView.Enabled = false;
                break;
            case EditPageViewType.Disable:
                myCurrentEntriesGridView.Enabled = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem with your code in CreateChildControls is that it is a mixture of control creation and data binding code. This isn’t appropriate, because ViewState is loaded between control creation and data binding!

Split your code in control creation code (CreateChildControls) and data binding code, running later in the page life cycle. The load event is a good place for data binding.

Further make sure that CreateChildControls is really called before your controls are used. I prefer to call EnsureChildControls in page init.

Answer (score 0):

Error says:

> control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control
>   tree that was used to save viewstate

This means that if you had some control on your page during save of the view state then it must be there during load of the view state after postback. I think you should check how your composite control creates children controls and make sure they are created after postback.

Comment: Well I've been stepping through the code, and it does seem to run the "CreateChildControls()" method on postback.  And the values that determine which controls should be created do not change during postback.  In other words, it is not dynamically changing the control collection on postbacks, only when it is first initialized.